# delete left join postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

**Problem:** I have the following two tables. I want to delete the rows of old data which are not present in temp data. Primary keys are id and scenario. I ran the following delete left join in postgres which unfortunately did not work out (it deletes the whole table):

```
DELETE
FROM old_data
USING old_data as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_data b ON (b.id = a.id AND b.scenario=a.scenario) 
      WHERE (b.scenario IS NULL AND a.scenario = 2)
```

Any ideas how to adjust the query?

```
## Old data
```

[image]

```
Temp data
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a left join for that:

```
DELETE FROM old_data od
where not exists (select * 
                  from temp_data td
                  where td.id = od.id 
                    AND td.scenario = od.scenario) ;
```

Comment: thanks! one follow-up question: assuming in the temp data would only be data for scenario = 2 available and I only want to delete the rows in old data from scenario=2 which are not present anymore in temp data while scenario = 1 is present in old data (i.e. keep rows of scenario = 1 in old data). do you also know how to do that?